# Builder design pattern with inheritance: is there a better way?

Tags: c#, generics, builder

I'm creating a series of builders to clean up the syntax which creates domain classes for my mocks as part of improving our overall unit tests.  My builders essentially populate a domain class (such as a `Schedule`) with some values determined by invoking the appropriate `WithXXX` and chaining them together.

I've encountered some commonality amongst my builders and I want to abstract that away into a base class to increase code reuse.  Unfortunately what I end up with looks like:

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder<T,BLDR> where BLDR : BaseBuilder<T,BLDR> 
                                          where T : new()
{
    public abstract T Build();

    protected int Id { get; private set; }
    protected abstract BLDR This { get; }

    public BLDR WithId(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        return This;
    }
}
```

Take special note of the `protected abstract BLDR This { get; }`.

A sample implementation of a domain class builder is:

```
public class ScheduleIntervalBuilder :
    BaseBuilder<ScheduleInterval,ScheduleIntervalBuilder>
{
    private int _scheduleId;
    // ...

    // UG! here's the problem:
    protected override ScheduleIntervalBuilder This
    {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public override ScheduleInterval Build()
    {
        return new ScheduleInterval
        {
            Id = base.Id,
            ScheduleId = _scheduleId
                    // ...
        };
    }

    public ScheduleIntervalBuilder WithScheduleId(int scheduleId)
    {
        _scheduleId = scheduleId;
        return this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Because BLDR is not of type BaseBuilder I cannot use `return this` in the `WithId(int)` method of `BaseBuilder`.

Is exposing the child type with the property `abstract BLDR This { get; }` my only option here, or am I missing some syntax trick?

Update (since I can show why I'm doing this a bit more clearly):

The end result is to have builders that build profiled domain classes that one would expect to retrieve from the database in a [programmer] readable format.  There's nothing wrong with...

```
mock.Expect(m => m.Select(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(
    new Schedule
    {
        ScheduleId = 1
        // ...
    }
);
```

as that's pretty readable already.  The alternative builder syntax is:

```
mock.Expect(m => m.Select(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(
    new ScheduleBuilder()
        .WithId(1)
        // ...
        .Build()
);
```

the advantage I'm looking for out of using builders (and implementing all these `WithXXX` methods) is to abstract away complex property creation (automatically expand our database lookup values with the correct `Lookup.KnownValues` without hitting the database obviously) and having the builder provide commonly reusable test profiles for domain classes...

```
mock.Expect(m => m.Select(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(
    new ScheduleBuilder()
        .AsOneDay()
        .Build()
);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All I can say is that if there *is* a way of doing it, I want to know about it too - I use *exactly* this pattern in my [Protocol Buffers port](http://github.com/jskeet/dotnet-protobufs/tree/master). In fact, I'm glad to see that someone else has resorted to it - it means we're at least somewhat likely to be right!

Comment: Yup looks like we're stuck with "abstract T This { get; }" I'll accept and close since I think the solution is all that is available.

Comment: I'm trying to find a relatively clear way to create builders and found that article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240756/Hierarchically-Implementing-the-Bolchs-Builder-Pat). It offers to cast it once.(protected BLDR _this; _this = (BLDR)this; return _this;), but i can't understand why the author added class WindowBuilder : WindowBuilder<WindowBuilder, Window> { } (Look complete example at the bottom of article). In this post I see almost the same pattern, but cfeduke uses class ScheduleIntervalBuilder :
    BaseBuilder<ScheduleInterval,ScheduleIntervalBuilder>...

Comment: Personaly I would probably implement each Builder without the base class. I always try not using this *self-generic pattern*: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Comment: @Pellared: But then you don't get the benefits of the situations where you want to deal with "any builder" or "any message" - and yes, those do occur. There are pros and cons with each approach.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I think you can use a simple cast to avoid the `abstract BLDR This { get; }`

The resulting code would then be:

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder<T, BLDR> where BLDR : BaseBuilder<T, BLDR>
                                           where T : new()
{
    public abstract T Build();

    protected int Id { get; private set; }

    public BLDR WithId(int id)
    {
        _id = id;
        return (BLDR)this;
    }
}

public class ScheduleIntervalBuilder :
    BaseBuilder<ScheduleInterval,ScheduleIntervalBuilder>
{
    private int _scheduleId;
    // ...

    public override ScheduleInterval Build()
    {
        return new ScheduleInterval
        {
                Id = base.Id,
                ScheduleId = _scheduleId
                    // ...
        };
    }

    public ScheduleIntervalBuilder WithScheduleId(int scheduleId)
    {
        _scheduleId = scheduleId;
        return this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Of course you could encapsulate the builder with

```
protected BLDR This
{
    get
    {
        return (BLDR)this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good implementation strategy for C#.

Some other languages (can't think of name of research language I've seen this in) have type systems that either support a covariant "self"/"this" directly, or have other clever ways to express this pattern, but with C#'s type system, this is a good (only?) solution.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I think "abstract T This { get; }" isn't such a high price to pay. :)